# Flux<Part>: No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: multipartform-data, spring-webflux

The issue https://jira.spring.io/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/SPR-16350/SPR-16350.html seems to be closed. However, just following https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-multipart, I suppose, using `@RequestBody` I should be able to reactively read multipart data as a stream.

What I've tried:

```
@PostMapping(
        value = "/upload",
        consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE
)
public Mono<Void> upload(@RequestBody Flux<Part> partFlux) {
    return partFlux
            .doOnError(error -> {
                System.out.println(error);
                System.out.println(error.getCause());
                Arrays.asList(error.getStackTrace()).forEach(System.out::println);
            })
            .then();
}
```

With a simple test (using `@AutoConfigureWebTestClient`):

```
@Test
public void uploadTest() throws Exception {
    webTestClient
            .post()
            .uri("/upload")
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            .body(
                    BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(
                            "file",
                            new MockMultipartFile
                                    (
                                            "file",
                                            "test.txt",
                                            "text/plain",
                                            "test string".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                                    )
                    )
            )
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectBody()
            .isEmpty();
}
```

This still gives me the same error as in the jira issue mentioned above.

I use: AdoptJDK 11.0.3, Spring Boot version 2.1.6

Output:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Request body input error
>   org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error: [simple type, class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile["inputStream"])
>   org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader$FluxSinkAdapterListener.onError(SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader.java:232)
>   org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader$SynchronossPartGenerator.lambda$accept$1(SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader.java:165)
>   reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onError(LambdaSubscriber.java:119)
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:228)
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:228)
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:228)
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:228)
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:228)
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onError(FluxContextStart.java:117)
>   reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:1748)
>   ...

Comment: you can try out using the https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-body-multipart way of building a request instead. I have no idea if that is any better

Comment: Works, if you post it as an answer, I'll except it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to build a request using the `MultipartBodyBuilder` that you can read more about here:

[webflux-client-body-multipart](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-body-multipart)